# Got a warning saying "PEP 8:no newline at end of file." Is this affecting my code?

Tags: python, while-loop, break, pep8

I’m trying to set up a while loop in pycharm that will only stop if you type in the number 10. Instead when I type in 10, it asks me to input another number. There aren’t any syntax errors when I run it. I got a warning that said “PEP 8: no new line at end of file”. Could this have anything to do with why it is not working the way it should?

I’ve attempted to print the number before using break.

```py
while True
    line = input(“number: “)
    if line == 10:
        break
```

I expected the program to stop when the user types 10 in the input. It continues to ask for numbers instead of stopping.

Comment: I corrected the formating - an indent to show the code layout.  It should show a syntax error on the `while True` line, which is missing a ':'.

Comment: `line` will never `==` an `int` object since it is a `str` object

Comment: What editor are you using that throws those "smart" quotes in your code? That would be part of the problem.

Comment: Try adding an extra empty line at the end. IDLE does that by default, but PyCharm might not.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code. You're missing a colon after the condition in the `while` loop (it should be `while True`), which is a syntax error.

More pertinently, your logic is faulty; the result of `input` is always a string, which will never compare equal to an integer; accordingly, you need to cast it. Since casting can fail, you also need to check the input accordingly; something like this, perhaps:

```
while True:
    line = input(“number: “)
    if (line.isdigit()) and (int(line) == 10):
        break
```

As for your original question, it doesn't really matter.

Strictly speaking, [a text file must end with a newline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file). Some programs don't work well if they don't.

In this day and age, and considering how high level Python - and its toolchain - is, you probably won't actually encounter any problems. Nevertheless, your IDE should automatically add a newline at the end (if not, you should be able to configure it to), and it is in general better to comply with PEP8 until you gain enough experience to understand when you shouldn't.